# How do I take screenshots and/or record debug output from Recovery Mode

Tags: recovery, screen-capture

I'm currently trying to repair a corrupted APFS volume in Recovery Mode and want to include some screenshots or copy/paste some Terminal output to then paste into a bug report. How do I accomplish this from Recovery Mode to then transfer to a working Mac on the same network to submit?

Comment: Take them on your phone and email/Airdrop them to yourself?

Comment: @NoahL Ah, old school!